# How to add multiple AMP modules to alfresco-sdk?

Tags: alfresco

I am new to alfresco-sdk. I am used to have old style AMP modules and then run ant script to combine them into alfresco WAR file.

I have followed tutorials of alfresco-sdk for

1. alfresco all in one
2. alfresco AMP
3. alfresco share

archetypes and it ran successfully.

I could not figure out if I have three different AMP modules, how can I combine them in one?

Say for example, currently I following AMP modules in my repo -

1. alfresco-DEF-AMP
2. alfresco-generic-AMP
3. alresco-ABC-AMP

What should I do such that when I give amp-to-war command, it takes  customization from above three modules and puts then into alfresco WAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use alfresco All-in-one archetype for that.

We can use overlays to include our custom modules such as

```
alfresco-DEF-AMP
alfresco-generic-AMP
alresco-ABC-AMP
```

to generate single WAR file (alfresco/repo.war)

Below link is very useful

http://docs.alfresco.com/sdk2.1/concepts/alfresco-sdk-advanced-add-custom-amps.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick with using a seperate archetype alfresco (AKA repository) AMP for each of your existing modules.

By Running the alfresco SDK maven build with target **mvn package** on each module, will create an amp file for you. These amps can then be deployed to your alfresco instance (with apply_amps.bat), just like you probably are used to, with ant builds.
 You don t have to execute the maven build via run.bat file, which starts alfresco with your module in an embedded container.

If you really want to combine them into one, I suppose you ll have to merge your code of the 3 modules into one module of type alfresco AMP, and still work the above way.